# How to launch editor like vi or emacs from node.js REPL?

Tags: node.js, editor, read-eval-print-loop

I want to launch an editor like vi or emacs from node.js REPL.

I have tried two approaches till now:

1. Node Addons

   Heres how my `editor.cc` looks like:

   ```
   const char *tempFile = "TEMP_FILE"; // File to be opened with the editor

   Handle<Value> launchEditor (const Arguments& args) {
       const char *editor = "vi";
       Local<String> buffer;

       pid_t pid = fork();
       if (pid == 0) {
           execlp(editor, editor, tempFile, NULL);

           // Exit with "command-not-found" if above fails.
           exit(127);
       } else {
           waitpid(pid, 0, 0);
           char *fileContent = readTempFile(); // Simple file IO code to read file.
           buffer = String::New(fileContent);
           free(fileContent);
       }
       return buffer;
   }


   // MAKE IT A NODE MODULE

   void Init(Handle<Object> target) {
       target->Set(String::NewSymbol("editor"), FunctionTemplate::New(launchEditor)->GetFunction());
   }

   NODE_MODULE(editor, Init)
   ```

   This worked when I had node v0.6.12 (compiled with `node-waf`), but
   when I updated node to v0.8.1, this code stopped working (compiled
   with `node-gyp`). The editor simply didn't appear, and the file
   content was read and returned (with emacs) or the editor was running as a background
   process (with vi)! Is there anything that I need to change for it to work with 0.8.1?

   Even if the editor is launched as background process, can I bring it to foreground from the code itself?
2. Child_process module

   ```
   spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
   editor = spawn('emacs', ['TEMP_FILE']);
   ```

   But this is not working properly. With emacs, it shows the error
   `input is not a tty` and vi gives a weird interface.

Can someone help with any of the solutions above, or suggest some other working solution?

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon one about a week ago, you should give it a try: [node-editor](https://github.com/substack/node-editor)